# issue with attribute 'disabled': false in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following query to enable disable query

```
if (checked == true) {


                      $('#lsltrXaxis, input[value^="ltrXaxis"]:not(:checked)').attr({ 'disabled': true, 'aria-disabled': true, 'checked': false, 'aria-selected': false }).addClass('ui-state-disabled');

                  }

                  }
```

I am disabling all non checked Items,

so it works, and it disable all uncheck items,
but when i click again on check items, i want it make it enable,

but its checked status returns me True

this is the line i am using for disable

```
  $('#lsltrXaxis, input[value^="ltrXaxis"]:not(:checked)').attr({ 'disabled': true, 'aria-disabled': true, 'checked': false, 'aria-selected': false }).addClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

This is working fine it disable all the rest items, other than selected one, but problem is when i again click on selected Item, it return checked True, and then it disable all items

Many issue with this code

```
disabled': true
```

when i add this in item item, then the selected item returns always true, when i remove this line from attribute adding line, then it works

What I am doing wrong

Any help will be appreciated

Thank You

Comment: may I suggest you post some code on http://jsfiddle.net/ to show your problem

Comment: The code is very lengthy this is a part of code, only I am facing problem when adding attribute disable : true,

Comment: Your situation looks quite confusing. I can't fully understand your bussiness flow from question. But, first of all, try to change `'disabled': true` on `'disabled':'disabled'` to have a correct XHTML attribute definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this code

$("selector").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```